# Get page title form url

Tags: 8, uri

How can I get the page title by its URL, for example http://example.com/en/news-events, which is not for the current page?

Comment: There is no easy solution, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178790/get-title-from-route. You can see what you would need to do in the path based breadcrumb builder: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder.php/function/PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder%3A%3Abuild/8.3.x

Comment: Is that URL alias of views page OR node URL alias ?

Comment: @parth.k This is an URL alias to my view page.

Answer (score 0):

From below code example you can get the page title as your requirement

```
 $path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias('/news-events');
 if(preg_match('/node\/(\d+)/', $path, $matches)) {
  $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($matches[1]);
 }
 echo $node->getTitle();
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: There is an extra ")" in your last line code. I used your code in my custom block hook and get the error: _Call to a member function getTitle() on null_

Comment: removed extra ")"

Comment: Yep. I removed extra ")" and still got same error.

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution for get title from view page url.

in your custom module
==> .module file

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

function display_form_mode_views_post_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
   print($view->getTitle($title));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer is too specific, since OP never mentioned whether it was on a Views page or not

Comment: Richard mentioned in his comment it was his view page URL

Comment: The question also says the URL is not for the current page, which means that any hook invoked for the current page is not invoked for the view associated to the given URL.